# Javascript variable with undefined value

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I have the following code but I do not understand why the result for answer variable is  "1234undefinedundefined" . Shouldn't it be "1234" ?

https://jsfiddle.net/JSmithd/t5roheuL/

```
var theanswer = "1,2,3,4";
var answerarray = theanswer.split(",");
var answer = "";
alert(theanswer.length);
for (z = 0; z < theanswer.length - 1; z++) { 
    if (answerarray[z] != "," && answerarray[z] != "undefined") { 
        answer = answer + answerarray[z];
    }
}
alert(answer);
```

Comment: `answerarray[z] != undefined` not `answerarray[z] != "undefined"`

Comment: You want `theanswerarray.length`, not `theanswer.length`...

Comment: just change to ``if (answerarray[z] != "," && answerarray[z] != undefined) {`` undefined without "

Comment: Also, for what you're doing here, you can use `answerarray.join('')`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JSmithd/t5roheuL/

Comment: it works both ways but I'd also recommend `typeof answerarray[z] !== "undefined"`

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for an answer, saw a few posting also mentioned != "undefined" . But when I tried, it did not work no matter which combination. Thank you for the answer. it works now. Will also look into answerarray.join('')

Answer (score 1):

Its a coding error in your for loop statement.

```
for (z = 0; z < theanswer.length - 1; z++)
```

theanswer.length == 7

because it's a string with 7 characters

this should really be

```
for (z = 0; z < answerarray.length; z++)
```

answerarray.length == 4

because its an ARRAY with 4 elements. You converted it to an array when you did the split.